# Can Ruby on Rails have multiple routes to one action while being able to differentiate in action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What I'd like to do is something like this

`get 'example/:id' => 'example#same_action'`

and also

`get 'slightly_different/:id' => 'example#same_action'`

but then be able to differentiate inside of `same_action()` as to which rule was used.

Is this better achieved by refactoring into model and partials?

Comment: you can access the same method either way. You can achieve what you want by changing parameters after url as like
slightly_different/:id?param=1
and then add logic into action based on the param

Comment: I don't hate it but I was hoping to avoid this if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
get ':something/:id', constraints: { something: /example|slightly_different/ }
```

and differentiate based on `something` param

Answer (score 1):

At a first glance, you should differentiate based on params, for example:

```
get 'example/:id' => 'example#same_action'
get 'slightly_different/:different_id' => 'example#same_action'
```

If you don't want to use a param, you could consider this tecnique:

```
get 'example/:my_url' => 'example#same_action', constraints: { my_url: /normal|slightly_different/ }
```

but you need to append at the beginning a common route

Comment: Ah.  Pretty good idea.  The only issue would be if it were routes without params?

Just 'example' and 'slightly_different' ?

Answer (score 1):

After putting a little more thought, this might be an option but it seems a little nasty:

`request.env['PATH_INFO']`  would return `"/slightly_different"`

Hoping there is a better way.